# Python/Tkinter - delete all objects in enclosed area

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to make a program where on click the program would delete all objects in enclosed area.

Here is my example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cv = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
cv.pack()

cv.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)

cv.create_line(60, 60, 80, 80)

cv.create_line(60, 80, 80, 60)

def onclick():

    todel = cv.find_enclosed(50, 50, 100, 100)
    cv.delete(todel)

cv.bind("<Button-1>", onclick())

root.mainloop()
```

On click it should delete the two lines in the rectangle, but for some reason it does not. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply `delete` to all items of the list

```
for d in todel:
    cv.delete(d)
```

or

```
any(map(cv.delete,todel))
```